# Google Custom Search Engine: How can I get all of my site indexed?

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing, google-programmable-search-engine

I am trying to use Google CSE for my website however without any success as it is not able to find half of the pages?

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Have you set yourself up in Webmaster Tools, and ideally submitted a sitemap also? Within the tools admin, you'll be able to see a lot of information about how and how much your site is generally indexed as well as things like [crawl errors](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35120) that will start giving you some idea why things might be missing.

Also, have you tried triggering an [on-demand index](http://www.google.com/support/customsearch/bin/answer.py?answer=115957)?

Comment: I have checked webmaster crawl data as well as added site again. Interestingly tags associated to the question are showing but not the question e.g. if i have asked as what is good widget1 (usique page www.domain.com/widget1.htm) and tagged it widget1. Widget1 is visible on domain.com/tag/widget1 but unique page does not appear and if serach for site:www.domain.com/widget1.htm it throws an error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure every page is accessible through static links (`<a href='...'>`) from the homepage directly or indirectly (i.e. homepage to page A and from page A to page B...).  You can also (but not instead of) submit a sitemap to the webmaster tools.

Also, give it some time, Google doesn't crawl all at once. It "assigns" some time and bandwidth to each site, so it may crawl a big site in a period of weeks.